# Finding a specific relationship's property on a connected node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The creation code for my sample graph is :

```
CREATE (a:Product { name:"A" }),(b:Product { name:"B" }),(c:Product { name:"C" }),(d:Product { name:"D" }),(e:Product { name:"E" }),(f:Product { name:"F" }),(s1:Supplier { name:"s1" }),(s2:Supplier { name:"s2" }),(s3:Supplier { name:"s3" }),(c)-[:Parent]->(b),(b)-[:Parent]->(a),(f)-[:Parent]->(d),(e)-[:Parent]->(d),(d)-[:Parent]->(a),(s1)-[:PRICE { value:10 }]->(a),(s2)-[:PRICE { value:20 }]->(c),(s3)-[:PRICE { value:30 }]->(d)
```

A picture of a sample Graph:

[image: Graph]

The idea is that E and F "inherit" the price from D's PRICE relationship, C has its price from its direct incoming PRICE relationship and B inherits from A. Needless to say the production graph is deeper with varying levels of price "inheritance". Indeed a Product could have more than one price (multiple suppliers) but that is for later.
For now, I want to create a query that will produce a price list for each Product.

The issue I have with my cypher query, is making the price inheritance generic, in that, the price may be from a node that is any number of Parent hops away.

Any suggestions welcome.

EDIT: Just to clarify: Prices are inherited from ONLY the first parent that has incoming PRICE relationships. So for example, E and F only take their price from D.

EDIT Number 2:

Thanks for all the responses. Nicole, I just seen your answer now as I came back to post my answer so I have added this as an edit rather than the answer,and marked yours as the answer to the orginal question, as I think your answer is the closest to what I eventually came up with.

One thing that I learnt posting this question is NOT to simplify the problem too much, I did hint at the many suppliers piece but that should have been made central.

With that out of the way, I want to post the solution that I have come up with.

Code to create new graph

```
CREATE (a:Product { name:"A" }),(b:Product { name:"B" }),(c:Product { name:"C" }),(d:Product { name:"D" }),(e:Product { name:"E" }),(f:Product { name:"F" }),(s1:Supplier { name:"s1" }),(s2:Supplier { name:"s2" }),(s3:Supplier { name:"s3" }),(c)-[:Parent]->(b),(b)-[:Parent]->(a),(f)-[:Parent]->(d),(e)-[:Parent]->(d),(d)-[:Parent]->(a),(s1)-[:PRICE { value:10 }]->(a),(s2)-[:PRICE { value:20 }]->(c),(s3)-[:PRICE { value:30 }]->(d),(s3)-[:PRICE{value:40}]->(f)
```

[image]

Added another PRICE quote from supplier S3 to Product F. The price list is to contain prices either explicitly stated for a product by a relationship or inherit a price from a parent product, but only inherit the first price for any given supplier. So in the new graph F gets the price 
directly from S3, doesn't inherit S3's price for D but does continue and inherit S1's price from A.

The query that I am currently working with is as follows:

```
MATCH
path = ((product)-[:Parent*0..]->(parentProduct)<-[price:PRICE]-(supplier:Supplier))
where single ( code in nodes(path) where (code)<-[:PRICE]-(supplier) )
with product,parentProduct,price,supplier
order by price.value
with product.name as ProductName, collect([supplier.name,price.value]) as PriceList
order by ProductName
return ProductName,PriceList
```

Giving the follow Price List :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
MATCH path = (p:Product)-[:Parent*0..]->(:Product)<-[r:PRICE]-(:Supplier)
WITH p, LENGTH(path) AS len, r.value AS prices
ORDER BY p.name, len
RETURN p.name AS product, HEAD(COLLECT(prices)) AS price
ORDER BY product
```

Result:

```
product price
      A    10
      B    10
      C    20
      D    30
      E    30
      F    30
```

This starts at a Product node and follows the Parent relationships to the nearest Product with an incoming PRICE relationship. Note that the *0.. takes care of Products that have a direct incoming PRICE relationship. For each Product, the paths are ordered by length ascending and you get the price from the shortest path.

See here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/ovhajx

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
match (s:Supplier)-[p:PRICE]->(prod:Product)<-[:parent*]-(other:Product)
where not (other)<-[:PRICE]-(s2:Supplier)
RETURN prod, other, p;
```

This attempts to build a list of all prices associated to products, following parent links returns `other` products with the same price.  The where clause guarantees that the other product linked by `:parent` relationships doesn't have its own local price.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately your snippet throws an error "s2 not defined (line 2, column 30 (offset: 102))
"where not (other)<-[:PRICE]-(s2:Supplier)" reading your description I have edited the command but so far unable to get a solution via it. I will report back when I have more time spend on it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
MATCH path=(p:Product)-[:Parent*0..]->(parent)<-[:PRICE]-(s)
WITH path,head(nodes(path)) as product
WITH product,min(length(path)) as size,collect(path) as allPaths 
UNWIND allPaths as path
WITH product,size,path,length(path) as length
WHERE size=length
RETURN product,last(relationships(path)).value;
```

This matches paths from the product to a supplier, determines the shortest path to the first supplier in the chain, and then filters on that length.